# How to remove Board and HR/CFO from Highchart organization?

Tags: highcharts, jquery-plugins, organization

I want to create organizational chart with Highchart like this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/organization-chart

How to remove Board and HR/CFO from chart?

Thank You,

Best Regards,

Eka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify `data` property and adapt `levels` and `nodes` to the changes.

```
data: [
  ['Shareholders', 'CEO'],
  ['CEO', 'CTO'],
  ['CEO', 'CPO'],
  ['CEO', 'CSO'],
  ['CEO', 'CMO'],
  ['CTO', 'Product'],
  ['CTO', 'Web'],
  ['CSO', 'Sales'],
  ['CMO', 'Market']
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lou32f1d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.data